# The LINQ expression could not be translated for base property

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have custom OrderBy implementation, it only works for types without inheritance, if I want order by field from base type I got The LINQ expression  could not be translated

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, string orderByProperty, bool desc)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderByProperty))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(orderByProperty));
    }

    var command = desc ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";

    var type = typeof(TEntity);

    var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var property = type.GetProperty(orderByProperty);
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, property);
    var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, param);
    var resultExpression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            command,
            new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType },
            source.Expression,
            Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));
    return (IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>)source.Provider.CreateQuery(resultExpression);
}
```

I am using entityframework core 2.2 but the very interesting thigs is that if I write just `source.OrderBy(x=>x.someBaseField)` then it works without any problem, so there must by something with my custom implementation

In error log I got also the translated query and it looks like this, intereresting is end part

```
orderby new SomeType() {NewField = [entity].DbField, Id = [entity].Id}.Id desc

orderByExpression.Body {p => p.Id}

resultExpression

.Call System.Linq.Queryable.OrderByDescending(
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
        .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
            .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
                .Constant<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[MyTypeView]>(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[MyTypeView]),
                '(.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[MyTypeView,System.Boolean]>)),
            '(.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[MyTypeView,System.Boolean]>)),
        '(.Lambda #Lambda3<System.Func`2[MyTypeView, MyTypeResult]>))
    ,
    '(.Lambda #Lambda4<System.Func`2[MyTypeResult,System.Guid]>))
```

Comment: I'd first try a slightly simpler version, without the "splitting by dots" - have you got *that* much working?

Comment: @JonSkeet Hi Jon, I just simplyfied it but the problem is the same.

Comment: Okay, good - that simplifies things. If you print out the `orderByExpression` and the `resultExpression`, do they look like you'd expect them to?

Comment: @JonSkeet for me looks ok, I updated the question, didn't include all lambdas definitions only template

Comment: Hmm... it looks okay to me as well. Out of interest, if you use a `List<T>` as a source via `AsQueryable`, does the code work? If not, a [mcve] showing that would be really useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen something like this before. The only difference between compiler generated and manual expression is the `ReflectedType` property of the `PropertyInfo` - in compiler generated code it's the same as `DeclaringType`, which in this case is the base class, while in the `PropertyInfo` obtained via `type.GetProperty` it is the derived type used to obtain it.

For some unknown reason (probably a bug) this is confusing EF Core. The workaround is to change the code as follows:

```
var property = type.GetProperty(orderByProperty);
if (property.DeclaringType != property.ReflectedType)
    property = property.DeclaringType.GetProperty(property.Name);
```

or use a helper method like this

```
static PropertyInfo GetProperty(Type type, string name)
{
    for (; type != null; type = type.BaseType)
    {
        var property = type.GetProperty(name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        if (property != null) return property;
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

In order to support nested properties, I would add the following helpers

```
static Expression Property(Expression target, string name) =>
    name.Split('.').Aggregate(target, SimpleProperty);

static Expression SimpleProperty(Expression target, string name) =>
    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(target, GetProperty(target.Type, name));
```

and then use

```
var propertyAccess = Property(param, orderByProperty);
```

and

```
new Type[] { type, orderByExpression.ReturnType },
```

inside the method in question.

Comment: I've had something similar, then tried your method. In both cases I'm getting: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<FixCode>.OrderByDescending(f => f.Domain.ShortName)' could not be translated. It does not work on nested properties - only on simple ones... Any ideas?

Comment: @Alexander The above works for nested properties. It's hard to tell you what's wrong in your concrete case w/o seeing it - there might be other factors causing it to fail to translate. First make sure that writing the same by hand works. If it does, prepare a minimal reproducible example and post your own question.

Comment: ah, I have figured it out :) My nested property was "ignored" in the OnModelCreating... Sorry.