# LINQ Expression could not be translated (Deep Query in EF Core)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, expression-trees, linq-expressions

My Error Message is as follows:

---

The LINQ expression

```
DbSet<WorkItemEntity>
  .Where(w => w.Company.Name.ToLower() != null && "com" != null && 
              w.Company.Name.ToLower().StartsWith("com"))
```

could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

---

I'm not sure which part it is that causes this, i thought ToLower/StartsWith are both supported?

The Query is generated by an Expression. The important part happens here:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyFilters<T, TOut>(this IQueryable<T> query, Dictionary<Expression<Func<T, TOut>>, Filter> parameters)
{
    foreach (var filterPair in parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "w");
            MemberExpression propertyExpression = filterPair.Key.Body as MemberExpression;

            var body = GetBody(filterPair, propertyExpression);

            if (body != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameterExpression));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            // Do not throw for invalid expressions
        }
    }
    return query;
}
```

and this is my "body"

```
var stringModel = filterPair.Value.Value as StringModel;
comparerExpression = Expression.Constant(stringModel.Value.ToLower());
string methodName = Enum.GetName(typeof(StringFilterType), filterType);
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(string).GetMethod(methodName, new Type[] { typeof(string) });
return Expression.Call(ToLowerMember(propertyExpression), methodInfo, comparerExpression);
```

Everything except the fulfillment of the query seems to work? Any ideas?

When I rewrite my own Query (the error), it works fine. So I guess it has to do with Reflection?

```
query = query.Where(w => w.Company.Name.ToLower().StartsWith("com"));
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities

Comment: Your final query is *client-side evaluation.*

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Usually LINQ is a lot like SQL.

`var items = from item in list select item where item.Company.Name.ToLower().StartsWith("com"))`

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/what-is-linq

Comment: So this is literally not possible as outsourcing Where-Functionality to an Expression is not supported? Do i understand this correctly?

Im trying to implement Filters by using expressions, not only top-level (which i was able to do) but also into Nested Properties.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's supported as shown in the bottom line, but I'm having trouble seeing what your exact question is. I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Outsourcing `Where` functionality to a Expression is unremarkable (if a bit obtuse).  See http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx.  Trying to do the same with Entity Framework Linq is a bit... problematic, unless you're willing to stick with expressions that are compatible with Entity Framework.

Comment: I'm for example Saying check the Property XYZ with Filter Equals, StartsWith, or whatever MethodInfo i pass.

I define the Expression like this: (WorkItemEntity w) => w.Company.Name

Comment: `var filters = new Dictionary<Expression<Func<WorkItemEntity, object>>, Filter>()
            {
                { (WorkItemEntity w) => w.Company.Name, new Filter(StringFilterType.StartsWith, new StringModel("Com")) }
            };


            query = query.ApplyFilters(filters);`

Im applying the filters to the existing query

Comment: It's also saying that this cannot be translated via Expression `.Where(w => w.Company.Name == "com")`

Comment: The query as lambda should translate into SQL alright (at least, with the Sql Server data provider it does). I wonder if `ToLower` makes sense though, because the generated SQL will use the database collations, which usually is case-insensitive. Also, this construction isn't sargable. The problem with your expression builder is that you don't use one `parameterExpression` (`w`). But as said: find an existing predicate builder.

Comment: There were some bugs with code generated property access expressions, you might be hitting oe of them - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295009/the-linq-expression-could-not-be-translated-for-base-property/55296106#55296106, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389115/why-linq-where-expression-after-select-gets-evaluated-locally-when-created-thr/57392731#57392731

Comment: EF Core 2 used to look through lambda calls, EF Core 3 does not. If you are trying to inline expressions from one lambda to another, you will need to replace every instance of `ParameterExpression`. In other words, `ApplyFilters` will fail if `body` uses any parameters.

Comment: So i used something called an ExpressionVisitor, i dont completely understand it but is it what made it work (i dont use it anymore in the final solution):

`class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
        {
            public ParameterExpression source;
            public Expression target;

            protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
            {
                return node == source ? target : base.VisitParameter(node);
            }
        }`

Comment: @paul _ Usually LINQ is a lot like SQL._ The syntax you describe (AKA keyword syntax) is only syntactic sugar which the compiler accepts and converts into calls to the underlying LINQ methods such as `.Where(...)` and `.Select(...)`.

Comment: You're not showing the definition of `ToLowerMember`. Is it possible that it's returning the wrong overload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this only covers property filtering on top-level properties (e.g. no relations). But if you do something like select(x => new xModel() { Name = x.Partner.Name}) you will be able to access "Name" by filtering after the Select of the Deep properties.

I had a solution working with Expression of the Deep Property but in the end it wold be more convenient to first Select and then Apply the Filters via Array in a one-liner.

You can see how i solved the String-Filtering as well in there.

Thanks for your help everyone! :)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using Shared.Models;
using Shared.Models.Filter;

namespace App.Extensions
{
    public static class FilterExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// FilterModel
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="TFilterType"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="query"></param>
        /// <param name="filter"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IQueryable<T> ApplyFilter<T, TFilterType>(this IQueryable<T> query, FilterModel<TFilterType> filter)
        {
            (Expression Body, ParameterExpression Parameter) value;

            if (filter.FilterType is NumberFilterType numberFilterType)
            {
                value = CreateNumberFilter<T, TFilterType>(filter, numberFilterType);
            }
            else if(filter.FilterType is DateTimeFilterType dateTimeFilterType)
            {
                value = CreateDateTimeFilter<T, TFilterType>(filter, dateTimeFilterType);
            }
            else if(filter.FilterType is StringFilterType stringFilterType)
            {
                value = CreateStringFilter<T, TFilterType>(filter, stringFilterType);
            }
            else if (filter.FilterType is BoolFilterType)
            {
                value = CreateBoolFilter<T, TFilterType>(filter);
            }
            else if (filter.FilterType is GuidFilterType)
            {
                value = CreateGuidFilter<T, TFilterType>(filter);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException(filter.FilterType.ToString());
            }

            return query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(value.Body, value.Parameter));

        }

        public static IQueryable<T> ApplyFilters<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, FilterPagingParameters parameters)
        {
            query = query.ApplyFilters(parameters.NumberFilters);
            query = query.ApplyFilters(parameters.DateTimeFilters);
            query = query.ApplyFilters(parameters.StringFilters);
            query = query.ApplyFilters(parameters.BoolFilters);
            query = query.ApplyFilters(parameters.GuidFilters);

            return query;
        }

        private static IQueryable<T> ApplyFilters<T, TFilterType>(this IQueryable<T> query, FilterModel<TFilterType>[] filters)
        {
            if (filters != null && filters.Any())
            {
                foreach (var filter in filters)
                {
                    query = query.ApplyFilter(filter);
                }
            }

            return query;
        }

        private static (Expression Body, ParameterExpression Parameter) CreateNumberFilter<T, TFilterType>(FilterModel<TFilterType> filter, NumberFilterType filterType)
        {
            var propertyExpression = GetExpression<T, decimal>(filter.Name);
            var parameter = propertyExpression.Parameters[0];
            var value1 = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToDecimal(filter.Value.Value));
            Expression body;

            if (filterType == NumberFilterType.Between)
            {
                var value2 = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToDecimal(filter.Value.Value2));
                var bodyMin = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(propertyExpression.Body, value1);
                var bodyMax = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(propertyExpression.Body, value2);

                body = Expression.AndAlso(bodyMin, bodyMax);

            }
            else if (filterType == NumberFilterType.Equals)
            {
                body = Expression.Equal(propertyExpression.Body, value1);
            }
            else if (filterType == NumberFilterType.GreaterThan)
            {
                body = Expression.GreaterThan(propertyExpression.Body, value1);
            }
            else if (filterType == NumberFilterType.GreaterThanOrEqual)
            {
                body = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(propertyExpression.Body, value1);
            }
            else if (filterType == NumberFilterType.LessThan)
            {
                body = Expression.LessThan(propertyExpression.Body, value1);
            }
            else if (filterType == NumberFilterType.LessThanOrEqual)
            {
                body = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(propertyExpression.Body, value1);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException(filterType.ToString());
            }

            return (body, parameter);
        }

        private static (Expression Body, ParameterExpression Parameter) CreateDateTimeFilter<T, TFilterType>(FilterModel<TFilterType> filter, DateTimeFilterType filterType)
        {
            var propertyExpression = GetExpression<T, DateTime>(filter.Name);
            var parameter = propertyExpression.Parameters[0];
            var value1 = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToDateTime(filter.Value.Value)); // TODO: ToDate Required?
            Expression body;

            if (filterType == DateTimeFilterType.Between)
            {
                var value2 = Expression.Constant(Convert.ToDateTime(filter.Value.Value2));
                var bodyMin = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(propertyExpression.Body, value1);
                var bodyMax = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(propertyExpression.Body, value2);

                body = Expression.AndAlso(bodyMin, bodyMax);

            }
            else if (filterType == DateTimeFilterType.Equals)
            {
                body = Expression.Equal(propertyExpression.Body, value1);
            }
            else if (filterType == DateTimeFilterType.GreaterThan)
            {
                body = Expression.GreaterThan(propertyExpression.Body, value1);
            }
            else if (filterType == DateTimeFilterType.GreaterThanOrEqual)
            {
                body = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(propertyExpression.Body, value1);
            }
            else if (filterType == DateTimeFilterType.LessThan)
            {
                body = Expression.LessThan(propertyExpression.Body, value1);
            }
            else if (filterType == DateTimeFilterType.LessThanOrEqual)
            {
                body = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(propertyExpression.Body, value1);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException(filterType.ToString());
            }

            return (body, parameter);
        }

        private static (Expression Body, ParameterExpression Parameter) CreateStringFilter<T, TFilterType>(FilterModel<TFilterType> filter, StringFilterType filterType)
        {
            // TODO: Try to make it the same way everywhere
            string methodName = Enum.GetName(typeof(StringFilterType), filterType);
            MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(string).GetMethod(methodName, new Type[] { typeof(string) });

            if(methodInfo == null)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException(filterType.ToString());
            }

            var propertyExpression = GetExpression<T, string>(filter.Name);
            var parameter = propertyExpression.Parameters[0];
            var value = Expression.Constant(filter.Value.Value as string);
            Expression body = Expression.Call(propertyExpression.Body, methodInfo, value);

            return (body, parameter);
        }

        private static (Expression Body, ParameterExpression Parameter) CreateGuidFilter<T, TFilterType>(FilterModel<TFilterType> filter)
        {
            var propertyExpression = GetExpression<T, Guid>(filter.Name);
            var parameter = propertyExpression.Parameters[0];
            var value = Expression.Constant(Guid.Parse(filter.Value.Value as string));
            Expression body = Expression.Equal(propertyExpression.Body, value);
            return (body, parameter);
        }

        private static (Expression Body, ParameterExpression Parameter) CreateBoolFilter<T, TFilterType>(FilterModel<TFilterType> filter)
        {
            var propertyExpression = GetExpression<T, bool>(filter.Name);
            var parameter = propertyExpression.Parameters[0];
            var value = Expression.Constant((bool)filter.Value.Value);
            Expression body = Expression.Equal(propertyExpression.Body, value);

            return (body, parameter);
        }

        private static Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> GetExpression<T, TProperty>(string propertyName)
        {
            // x =>
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            // x.Name
            var mapProperty = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
            // (object)x.Name
            var convertedExpression = Expression.Convert(mapProperty, typeof(TProperty));
            // x => (object)x.Name
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TProperty>>(convertedExpression, parameter);
        }
    }
}
```